# Book I read in the middle 80s about a werewolf killed by sharks

Tags: story-identification, novel, books, werewolf

I think the main female character was Maeve. It talked about wolfsbane. Hunting in the woods at night. Something about being on a boat. Sharks killing the werewolf at the end of the book.

Comment: Did the sharks then turn into werewolf-sharks?

Comment: My +1 just for the title. I hope you find the book!

Comment: @tbrookside Hmm .. "WereShark Apocalypse"I wonder if I can pitch that idea to the Sci-fi channel?  Followed by a sequel about Zombie Sharks.  Which raises the question of why only humans seem to be werewolves, zombies or vampires?

Comment: Peter - my point exactly.  That werewolf probably didn't go down without a fight.  Werewolf bites shark, moon comes up...Sci Fi network movie of the week.

Comment: Sharks come in, werewolf goes out. Never a miscommunication. You can't explain that.

Comment: Would a werewolf-shark still have perfect hair?

Answer (score 5):

Wolffile by Jack Woods (1988).
Took me FOREVER to find it. Such a weird book.

The [ending according to Deviancy](https://stephenking.com/xf/index.php?threads/calling-all-spielberg-fans.20205/):

> In Wolffile, a werewolf book that has been out of print for eons, the good guy, with the curse, saves the day but then realizes he has to end his life before he loses his good side and he's like, "what predator can kill a werewolf". He realizes the great white shark is the most fearsome predator so he jumps off a cliff into the ocean where he gets torn apart by a great white.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please [edit] in some points as to why you think this is what the OP is looking for? A synopsis would help too

Comment: It's a somewhat obscure book so I added the one summary of the ending that I could find for you.